# Pushing excel cells into Teradata (or other database) format

Tags: java, database, teradata

I'm having a hard time visualizing a good way to perform this. As you can see by the below code, I'm going through every row and getting values for each cell. However, when actually running the query to add them to a table, it's easier if you can input a whole row at a time. There's enough columns/variability though where I don't want to make a separate value for each column in the excel document. Any ideas on how to run this more efficiently?

```
for (int i=1; i<rowNum; i++) {
                    XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i) ;
                        for (int j = 0; j<colNum; j++) {
                            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j) ;
                            String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            data[i][j] = value ;
                            System.out.println("the value is " + value);
                            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO databasetable VALUES(" + value + ")");
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Not really following as the code inserts a new record for each cell (not each row).  Anyway, teradata probably provides import tools.  is java required?

Comment: I would rather export into CSV and fastload it - pretty straightforward and takes seconds on 64k+ sheets. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn an iterator on your worksheet to have it more efficient.

Something like the below

```
 public static Vector read(String fileName)    {
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
    try{
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            List list = new ArrayList();
            while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                list.add(myCell);
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement(list);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

Comment: Interesting choice to use `Vector` in 2017.

Comment: Actually I wanted to mention about the iterator to him... datastructure is on your choice :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using concentation and just inserted a , between each value in the for loop.